# Managing application variables/properties on IIS

Tags: c#, .net, iis

In my IIS I want to be able to load some variables from an external file.

Reading them from the web.config is a possibility but if I will want to update the variable without restarting, it will require me to edit all the web.config files in the cloud.
Reading them from a centralized db is also an option but some of my apps dont require  a connection.

What is a recommended way to manage application variables for IIS.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way is a `Web.config` file, that's why there is a built-in `appSettings` section. Now, as far as updating variables without restarting, you wouldn't have to edit them in the cloud at all. Have a copy of those `Web.config` files locally, in a testing environment that's like PROD, and then update them there first. Then you can test those changes and upload the entire `Web.config` file which will cause the application pool to reset automatically.

#### EDIT

With more information now available because of the OP's comments -another good solution may be to leverage the `machine.config` instead of the `web.config` for those settings that needs to be changed across multiple websites on the same server, especially if it's time sensitive that the applications see the change.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't referring to testing problems, I was referring to discrepancy. For example, if I have 100 machines - I need to save the web.config one by one and fast in order to avoid discrepancy. And I other problems. i.e.  this will make the web.config huge, coupled with my apps, and it will require restart on each change. The solution is possible, as I have mentioned, but I came here to find out if there is a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want to have an application restart (which both web.config and machine.config will do), I would recommend keeping it to custom settings object that can be responsible for updating itself independently. Consider a serializable object with settings that appear in a NameValueCollection (similar to a web.config or app.config file). This would allow you to add settings similarly. Some steps to consider:

1. Add a shared directory to a common network location so that you only have 1 copy of the file itself for all websites. Something like `\\somecommonserver\shared\configuration\`.
2. Add a static application variable to the code base so that each application pool will have a record of the last date/time the file was updated --> `Application["CustomConfigLastUpdate"] = configFileInfo.LastWriteTimeUtc;`    (I recommend using UTC because servers time may differ, but UTC does not)
3. Each time the settings are accessed may be a bit too heavy, but at some determined interval (each access, every 5/15/60 minutes, whatever) check if the `configFileInfo.LastWriteTimeUtc` property is greater than what is stored in the application variable, then you need to go get a fresh copy of the settings.
4. Create your custom object with the `[Serializable]` attribute and provide it a `LoadFromXmlFile` method that receives a filename as an argument whose responsibility is to repopulate itself.

I have done this before to achieve a similar goal, but I do not have those code samples here at my office. Here is a good SO question that has a relevant answer with code describing similar behavior: [How to Deserialize XML document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364253/how-to-deserialize-xml-document)